# Platform Encryption how to do in salesforce?

Tags: encryption

Can any one explain me what is Platform Encryption? Is just to Encryption of date for security reason. eg: Encryption of credit card number. Please help me what are the methods to Encrypt data in saleforce.

Answer (score 1):

Classic encryption provides 1 field type - text - that is encrypted 128 bit, masked from all users who do not have "view encrypted data" permission.

Platform encryption (a paid add-on, part of SF Shield) allows other data types to be encrypted- dates, numbers, and encrypts at 256-bit at rest. Same permission applies, and is not granular. View encrypted means view any and all encrypted fields that I can see.

PE also can encrypt documents, attachments. Rights behave different from fields. If I have rights to the document, I can view unencrypted.

Some limitations apply such as sorting & SOQL order by.  You can turn on/off for individual fields. Old documents or field values are not necessarily encrypted when you flip a switch.  You must touch or update a record for a field to encrypt; must contact SF to encrypt old files.

Comment: It would be useful to link to the Salesforce help for the topic too.